# accessible mega menu (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, megamenu

I have been researching how to make a accessible mega (multi-level) menu.  By accessible, I mean screen reader friendly and usable for keyboard only users.

Most samples i found online use the adobe model and are some alternate of this menu, but they all seem to be built using the jQuery plugin.  Has anyone used or read a good sample on some similar solution that does not have a dependency on jQuery?

Here is the menu I am referencing that uses the jQuery:
http://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/

Comment: what do you mean with "accessible mega menu"?

Comment: updated question with some explanation and sample menu I was referring to

Comment: Why don't you use the code from the sample you showed us and rewrite it to vanilla JS?

Comment: @Alp - Interesting -- I honestly had not thought of that yet. I need to read everything the plugin in achieving and make sure its able to convert.

Comment: That would be the best way to start. If you are experiencing specific problems, create an online example (jsfiddle, jsbin, codepen, ...) and ask a new question.

Comment: Button menu or menu bar are desktop application patterns. It's tricky to make it truly accessible on web pages. You are better off using table of contents, if possible. FYI, I [blogged](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/technical/2020/08/17/a11y-nav-dropdown-menu.html) about this issue.